# Avoiding collisions when extending third-party Python packages

Tags: python

I am working on a project that extends an existing and very active Python package - we'll call it `packageA`. Our package, `packageB` adds some functionality that is outside the scope of `packageA`, but relies heavily on a class from `packageA`.

We want the contents of `packageA` to be readily available to users of `packageB` with out having to do the following:

```py
import packageA as pkgA
import packageB as pkgB
```

and then have to keep track of which classes and methods come from which package.

Currently, the `__init__.py` file in `packageB`'s base directory contains the following:

```py
import packageA
from packageA import *
```

I am concerned about potential collisions with our package. My thought was to  give the package a structure like:

```
packageB/
    __init__.py
    packageA/
        __init__.py
```

then remove the import from `packageB`'s `__init__.py` and move it to the `packageA` `__init__.py` where I could then import only the classes and methods needed into the `packageB` namespace. Users could still access `packageA` through the `packageB.packageA` namespace.

Is there an accepted best practice for doing this sort of thing?

Comment: Can package A be installed in your environment or do you want/need it in the directory tree?

Comment: @paisanco The package could be installed in our environment, but we want the interface for our package to be as simple as possible. There is a specific class in packageA that we would like to be available from our package without users having to import it separately from packageA. I had considered simply extending the class, but we are not adding any new methods to it.